# search algorithm in multi level list

Tags: c#, list, search, recursion

i have a c# class

```
public class treeItem
{
    public string parentName { get; set; }
    public int index { get; set; }
    public List<treeItem> children { get; set; }
    public treeItem()
    {
        children = new List<treeItem>();
    }

}
```

i can fill it and sort it by index but i have a problem in search of index in 3rd or n level 
function to add index

```
    void AddIndexToTree(List<treeItem> children)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < children.Count; i++)
        {
            count++;
            children[i].index = count;
            if (children[i].children.Count > 0)
            {
                AddIndexToTree(children[i].children);
            }
        }
    }
```

i try to create a search function but have a problem in n level that i remove item from list so i send a copy of list to function but in n level it delete from the original list

```
    treeItem getParentNode(int index, List<treeItem> searchList)
    {
        if (searchList.Count == 1)
        {
            if (searchList[0].index == index)
            {
                return searchList[0];
            }
            else if (searchList[0].children.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < searchList[0].children.Count; i++ )
                {
                    if (searchList[0].children[i].index == index)
                        return searchList[0].children[i];
                }
                List<treeItem> tempList = searchList[0].children;
                return getParentNode(index, tempList);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int length = searchList.Count;
            int mid;



            if( length % 2 == 0)
            {
                mid = length / 2;
                if (length != 2)
                    mid--;
            }
            else
            {
                mid = length / 2;
            }


            if (searchList[mid].index == index)
                return searchList[mid];

            if(searchList[mid].index > index)
            {
                searchList.RemoveRange(mid, searchList.Count - mid );
                return getParentNode(index, searchList);
            }
            else
            {

                if (searchList.Count > 2 && searchList[mid + 1].index < index )
                    searchList.RemoveRange(0, mid + 1);
                else
                    searchList.RemoveRange(0, mid);
                return getParentNode(index, searchList);
            }

        }

        return null;

    }
```

any help in my code or another algorithm please ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand the question. Too much noise, I think. Can you [edit] your question to reflect only the problem at hand, with only the relevant code?

Comment: I think you add function needs improvements.  You are not adding items correctly so you aren't finding them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a simple recursive search for a specific index in a tree made up from your class: (of course, this should be a method in your class)

```
public treeItem Find(int index)
{
    if(this.Index == index)
        return this;
    foreach(var child in this.children)
        return child.Find(index);

    return null; // Index was not found in the current treeItem or any of it's children.
}
```

Please note that if the treeItems in your children property are ordered by index, you can use a binary search (which is what I think you tried to do).

Comment: thank you for your help i already try to use binary search 
but i have a problem that when i remove item from list => it will remove item from original list